# Noise for a switched capacitor circuit

Tags: capacitor, noise, switched-capacitor

I have a switched capacitor circuit that looks like below:
[image]

It operates at 80MHz to realize a 625k resistor. It works fine in the circuit. I tested with VDAC(input)=1.8V and the voltage at the right is 1.5V. Average current of 0.46uA flows in the circuit.

However, I am very much concerned about the practical implementation problems (noise). When I found the noise voltage of this circuit at 100kHz bandwidth, it comes out as:
$$\frac{K.T}{C}.100kHz = 0.0207$$ which is -33dB.

The input referred noise requirement of my circuit is around -110 dB. Am i doing something wrong or its just that the switched capacitor is not feasible?

Even if I try to add bigger capacitor in parallel, it can improve the accuracy, however, the noise voltage still cannot match to -110 dB.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you using for switches?

Comment: What is the \$K\$ in your noise equation?  What is the \$-33\mathrm{dB}\$ with respect to?

Comment: And how did you derive your noise equation?

Comment: @TimWescott I used the noise power, vn^2(rms)=KT/C, where $$K$$ is boltzmann constant and C is the capacitance. Now, the noise power = 20*log10(vn^2(rms)). Well, I guess -33dB is with respect to the signal level (0dB) (full scale of 1V).

Comment: @laptop2d well, inside a 16-bit ADC of an SNR around 84-100 dB, which is why I am skeptical. On top of that, I am using several units of this (around 10), guessing that would degrade the ADC performance in practical scenario.

Comment: for switch-caps, using 10 pF value, the RMS noise for ANY VALUE OF RESISTOR will be 20 microVolts RMS. The resistor+capacitor set the timeconstant and thus the bandwidth, but sqrt(K*T/C) defines the noise.

Answer (score 3):

You did not calculate the noise correctly. 
\$\frac{kT}{C}\$ is the integrated noise power which includes the Bandwidth of the circuit. So, you do not multiply it by bandwidth, bandwidth is multiplied when noise power spectral density is considered.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYD9xD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To calculate the noise in your circuit, consider the above schematic. In one phase of the switching period, the capacitor C is connected (via \$SW_1\$) to the input voltage while it is connected to the output (\$C_{out}\$) in the second phase (via \$SW_2\$).
**In \$\phi_1\$ (\$SW_1\$ closed and \$SW_2\$ open):**
A noise charge will be sampled on the \$C_{out}\$ capacitor. From thermodynamics, we know that each degree of freedom has energy of \$\frac{KT}{2}\$ in thermal equilibrium. Since voltage/charge is the only state of the capacitor, noise energy stored should be:
$$\frac{\overline{q_{o_n}^2}}{2C_o} = \frac{kT}{2}$$
$$\overline{q_{o_n}^2} = kTC_o$$
**In \$\phi_2\$ (\$SW_2\$ closed and \$SW_1\$ open):**
From similar reasoning as above, a noise charge will be sampled on the capacitor \$C\$ given by:
$$\overline{q_{n}^2} = kTC$$

Since in this phase both the capacitors are in parallel, a charge redistribution will happen, which after a simple math gives the following final charge on the output capacitor \$C_o\$:
$$Q_{o_n} = \frac{C_o}{C_o+C}(q_n+q_{o_n})$$.
Since the noise charges on the capacitors are uncorrelated, we get:
$$\overline{Q_{o_n}^2} = (\frac{C_o}{C_o+C})^2(\overline{q_{n}^2}+\overline{q_{o_n}^2})$$
Substituting the values, we get the noise charge of:
$$\overline{Q_{o_n}^2} = \frac{kTC_o^2}{C_o+C}$$
Thus, the output voltage noise becomes:
$$\overline{v_{o_n}^2} = \frac{kT}{C_o+C}$$
Assuming, you have \$C=C_o=20fF\$, the output noise power comes out to be \$-69.8dB\$.